# Magento 2 how to create customer file attribute

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, customer-attribute

Magento 2 how to create customer file attribute,file type must be csv,doc,xlsx

I search and also tried but not working.

Here is my code - InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace W3solver\Callforprice\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {

    protected $customerSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function upgrade( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4') < 0) {

            $setup->startSetup();
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'twilio_image', [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Twilio Image',
                'input' => 'file',
                "source" => '',
                'required' => false,
                'default' => '0',
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 210,
                'position' => 210,
                'system' => false,
            ]);

            $image = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'twilio_image')
                    ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],
            ]);

            $image->save();
            $setup->endSetup();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mised the 'backend' =>'Backend file path' attribute value.

Comment: @ShekharSuman Please check this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275635/magento-2-uncaught-referenceerror-base64-is-not-defined/275648?noredirect=1#comment392886_275648

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine. If you are below Magento 2.3.1 then you need to change line of code to make it work.

```
$attributesInfo = [
        'upload_documents' => [
            'label' => 'Twilio Image',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'image',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            "source" => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'position' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]
    ];
```

Here's github [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/19988) change file after compare with git file.

Comment: yes thanks i solved already

Comment: Good to hear that Magento is stable :)